# Wireshark mute..why?

Tags: wireshark

I have two host+one router

```
192.168.0.1 router
192.168.0.2 pc
192.168.0.5 macos
```

On pc i want to capture all packets of macos with wireshark

Interface on pc is bridged,br0

I put br0 in promisc mode and after setting wireshark filter to

```
ip.host==192.168.0.5
```

I can see ONLY packets from pc to mac(for example,icmp pjng),but not packets from mac to internetand other nodes.

Why?

Comment: Are the replies (for example for the ICMP Ping Echo Requests) are received by "pc" at all? (Is the ICMP Command working correctly?) Do you have a firewall active? If you're not using any more filters, you should see all packages to and from the host. By the way, "ip.host" is for DNS-Names, you can/should use ip.addr for your purposes.

Comment: The bridge will forward only to ports where the destination MAC address is known to be. Try wireshark on the physical interface to the network, not on the internally facing bridge interface.